# active record omit insert when value exists

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I  normally parse a data array to the db obj as follows

```
$this->db->update('myTable', array('col1' => "foo", 'col2' => 'bar' ,'col3' => 'abc'), array('id' => $id));
```

Is there a way of only updating the columns that have a null value? Currently i'm having to run a query first and then loop through. Not very efficient.

Comment: yes possible, which column you want to check NULL?

Comment: Just update all columns. Columns that have `null` value will be updated, other columns won't be changed if the values stored in columns and your data array are equal.

Comment: @AlexanderPopov the values may not be equal. I do not want new values updating old values, unless they are null.

Comment: @RejoanulAlam For example if col3 in the database is null the i want the new value updated. If the col3 in the database has a value then i want the col3 data ignored. This could apply to any column and any amount of times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of solutions:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE myTable SET col1 = IF(col1 IS NULL, ?, col1), col2 = IF(col2 IS NULL, ?, col2), col3 = IF(col3 IS NULL, ?, col3)';
$this->db->query($sql, ['foo', 'bar', 'abc']);
```

or

```
$this->db->set('col1', 'IF(col1 IS NULL, "foo", col1)', FALSE)
      ->set('col2', 'IF(col2 IS NULL, "bar", col2)', FALSE)
      ->set('col3', 'IF(col3 IS NULL, "abc", col3)', FALSE)
      ->update('myTable');
```